# "message sent to deallocated object" after passing an instance to another View Controller

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I've a NSMutableArray containing instances of my model class called PropertyData (only properties and no methods). In my app, there is a "View on map" button which when tapped set this NSMutableArray in the property of the Map View Controller before pushing its view on top of the navigation. The Map View controller successfully received this array (with NSLOG I printed out the total items received in the map view controller) but when looping through it I got this error:

```
[PropertyData lat] message sent to deallocated instance
```

Any idea why ?

Thx for helping,

Stephane

P.S:

In the first view controller data are stored to an ivar (declared as a NSMutableArray property in interface and then synthesize) called **rqst_entries** and here's how it switches to Map view:

```
-(void)show_map 
{
   PropertiesMapViewController *pMapView = [[PropertiesMapViewController alloc] init];
   pMapView.entries = self.rqst_entries; // pMapView.entries is alsi a NSMutableArray
   [self.navigationController pushViewController:pMapView animated:YES];
}
```

Here is the code where it crashes:

```
if(self.entries != nil)
{
   NSLog(@"received items count=%d",[self.entries count]);
   NSNumberFormater *nf = [[NSNumberFormater alloc] init];
   for(PropertyData *property_data in self.entries)
   {
     if(property_data==nil) continue;
     [nf setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
     // CRASH OCCURS HERE:
     NSNumber *lat = [nf numberFromString:property_data.lat]; 
   }

}
```

Comment: Post your code where app is crashing

Comment: A pure issue of memory leak. Will you please post some code?

Comment: could you show some code - otherwise it's hard to guess where the problem could be.

Comment: What property type have you declared for the mutable Array in Map View Controller ?Since you are setting it from some other view have you retailed the received array from previous view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make sure that the `entries` property of `PropertiesMapViewController` has the retain attribute:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray * entries;
```

Comment: I declared it like this: @property (nonatomic,retain) NSMutableArray *entries; so pretty the same as you suggest